# What is the difference between null=True and blank=True in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

When we add a model field in Django we generally write:

```
models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

The same is done with `ForeignKey`, `DecimalField` etc. What is the basic difference between:

1. `null=True` only
2. `blank=True` only
3. `null=True` and `blank=True`

in respect to different (`CharField`, `ForeignKey`, `ManyToManyField`, `DateTimeField`) fields? What are the advantages/disadvantages of using option 1, 2, or 3?

Comment: You have nice answers about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159310/why-are-blank-and-null-distinct-options-for-a-django-model and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384098/in-django-models-py-whats-the-difference-between-default-null-and-blank

Comment: Good reading: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/28/django-tips-difference-between-blank-and-null/

Comment: Yes, I also have this usecase with `ForeignKey` with `blank=True`, but without `null=True`. When the model is saved, I want to automatically "publish" it by creating a published entry out of it. So I cannot save `null` to the database, as every model has to be "published", but I want to be able to leave the field empty in admin.

Comment: I think you may be interested in [
Save empty, nullable CharField's as null rather than as an empty string](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4136). There are many discussions about this, and a very practical problem you may encounter (eg. you want to add a openid url for each user which can be null and should be unique).

Comment: Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and TextField. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/

Answer (score 1615, accepted):

`null=True` sets `NULL` (versus `NOT NULL`) on the column in your DB. Blank values for Django field types such as `DateTimeField` or `ForeignKey` will be stored as `NULL` in the DB.

`blank` determines whether the field will be required in forms. This includes the admin and your custom forms. If `blank=True` then the field will not be required, whereas if it's `False` the field cannot be blank.

The combo of the two is so frequent because typically if you're going to allow a field to be blank in your form, you're going to also need your database to allow `NULL` values for that field. The exception is `CharField`s and `TextField`s, which in Django are *never* saved as `NULL`. Blank values are stored in the DB as an empty string (`''`).

A few examples:

```
models.DateTimeField(blank=True) # raises IntegrityError if blank

models.DateTimeField(null=True) # NULL allowed, but must be filled out in a form
```

Obviously, Those two options don't make logical sense to use (though there might be a use case for `null=True, blank=False` if you want a field to always be required in forms, optional when dealing with an object through something like the shell.)

```
models.CharField(blank=True) # No problem, blank is stored as ''

models.CharField(null=True) # NULL allowed, but will never be set as NULL
```

`CHAR` and `TEXT` types are never saved as `NULL` by Django, so `null=True` is unnecessary. However, you can manually set one of these fields to `None` to force set it as `NULL`. If you have a scenario where that might be necessary, you should still include `null=True`.

Comment: In your explanation, models.DateTimeField(blank=True) you say that if this DateTimeField is left blank, an IntegrityError is raised.  But I thought that blank=True means that the field doesn't have to be filled in by the user, so why the IntegrityError?

Comment: `IntegrityError` is raised when Django attempts to save the record to the database. The field is not required to be filled in by the user, and that's the problem because at the database level it's not null.

Comment: I think user798719 is referring to the value of blank, which should be False instead of True in your example:   models.DateTimeField(blank=False) # raises IntegrityError if blank

Comment: No, Chris is trying to point out why having blank=True without having null=True would cause problems in a DateTimeField.

Comment: Note that you may `blank=True` for a field entered by the system.

Comment: @user798719 the field does not have to be filled by the user, but should assign some value to that field before saving that object to database(for eg:in the save method of that model).

Comment: NOTE to Oracle users: It is not true that "`CHAR` and `TEXT` are NEVER saved as `NULL` by Django". It is true for most backends, but Oracle will force an empty string to NULL, so the Django Oracle backend is an exception to the above statement [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.null)

Comment: is nobody going to mention the combination of: `blank=True`, `null=False`, `default="something"`?

Comment: @ChrisPratt I'm using Django in backend. Does this mean empty strings from form fields in my frontend will be interpreted as null when I post to an endpoint?

Comment: You don't need the combo of the two if you provide a default, unless you want to allow the field to explicitly set the value as None instead of the default.

Comment: "CHAR and TEXT types are never saved as NULL by Django" - 
for `CharField(blank=False, null=True)` django admin will save blank as null.
It's the default behavior since version 1.11 and works for all db backends
[(source)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1104)

Comment: Note that for Oracle null and blank can be the same sometimes. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/databases/#null-and-empty-strings

Comment: As of this comment, ONLY the oracle backend interprets empty strings as null. All other backends in `django.db.backends` DO NOT consider them to be the same. https://github.com/django/django/blob/c317e81378a15379cba4abc289d9519ee0335a80/django/db/backends/oracle/features.py#L15

Answer (score 173):

This is how the ORM maps `blank` & `null` fields for Django 1.8

```
class Test(models.Model):
    charNull        = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    charBlank       = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    charNullBlank   = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)

    intNull         = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    intBlank        = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    intNullBlank    = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    dateNull        = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    dateBlank       = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    dateNullBlank   = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

The database fields created for **PostgreSQL 9.4** are :

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
  id              serial                    NOT NULL,

  "charNull"      character varying(10),
  "charBlank"     character varying(10)     NOT NULL,
  "charNullBlank" character varying(10),

  "intNull"       integer,
  "intBlank"      integer                   NOT NULL,
  "intNullBlank"  integer,

  "dateNull"      timestamp with time zone,
  "dateBlank"     timestamp with time zone  NOT NULL,
  "dateNullBlank" timestamp with time zone,
  CONSTRAINT Test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

The database fields created for **MySQL 5.6** are :

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
     `id`            INT(11)     NOT  NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,

     `charNull`      VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
     `charBlank`     VARCHAR(10) NOT  NULL,
     `charNullBlank` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,

     `intNull`       INT(11)     NULL DEFAULT NULL,
     `intBlank`      INT(11)     NOT  NULL,
     `intNullBlank`  INT(11)     NULL DEFAULT NULL,

     `dateNull`      DATETIME    NULL DEFAULT NULL,
     `dateBlank`     DATETIME    NOT  NULL,
     `dateNullBlank` DATETIME    NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Comment: In other words, `blank` has no effect on the database, and `null` controls whether the database column allows `NULL` values. This answer is a really long way of saying that, and doesn't provide any useful information about `blank`.

Comment: @CarlMeyer : I wanted to see how it would map to the database and shared since it would save time for others to do the same. Theory vs example make a difference when it comes to assimilating and committing to memory. In fact, I went out of the way to add the mapping for a database I wasn't using. Thanks for the downvote. The number of people who found this useful obviously disagree with you.

Comment: It might be a useful answer if you drew some summary conclusions from the data presented, but I don't think that presenting a raw data dump is a useful answer. In this case it is actually a misleading answer, since (without further comment) it implies that the effect of both `blank` and `null` should be reflected in the database columns, when in fact `blank` affects only Python handling, not database columns. Others are free to upvote if they found it useful; it's also possible for people who are misled by a misleading answer to _think_ it was useful.

Comment: The accepted answer which is almost 3 years old explains everything in detail. There's no point in repeating the same info here.

Answer (score 159):

It's crucial to understand that the options in a Django model field definition serve (at least) two purposes: defining the database tables, and defining the default format and validation of model forms. (I say "default" because the values can always be overridden by providing a custom form.) Some options affect the database, some options affect forms, and some affect both.

When it comes to `null` and `blank`, other answers have already made clear that the former affects the database table definition and the latter affects model validation. I think the distinction can be made even clearer by looking at use cases for all four possible configurations:

- `null=False`, `blank=False`: This is the default configuration and means that the value is required in all circumstances.
- `null=True`, `blank=True`: This means that the field is optional in all circumstances. As noted below, though, this is *not* the recommended way to make string-based fields optional.
- `null=False`, `blank=True`: This means that the form doesn't require a value but the database does. There are a number of use cases for this:

  - The most common use is for optional string-based fields. As [noted in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null), the Django idiom is to use the empty string to indicate a missing value. If `NULL` was also allowed you would end up with two different ways to indicate a missing value. (If the field is also `unique`, though, you'll have to use `null=True` to prevent multiple empty strings from failing the uniqueness check.)
  - Another common situation is that you want to calculate one field automatically based on the value of another (in your `save()` method, say). You don't want the user to provide the value in a form (hence `blank=True`), but you do want the database to enforce that a value is always provided (`null=False`).
  - Another use is when you want to indicate that a `ManyToManyField` is optional. Because this field is implemented as a separate table rather than a database column, [`null` is meaningless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18244527/2395796). The value of `blank` will still affect forms, though, controlling whether or not validation will succeed when there are no relations.
- `null=True`, `blank=False`: This means that the form requires a value but the database doesn't. This may be the most infrequently used configuration, but there are some use cases for it:

  - It's perfectly reasonable to require your users to always include a value even if it's not actually required by your business logic. After all, forms are only one way of adding and editing data. You may have code that is generating data that doesn't need the same stringent validation you want to require of a human editor.
  - Another use case that I've seen is when you have a `ForeignKey` for which you don't wish to allow [cascade deletion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete). That is, in normal use the relation should always be there (`blank=False`), but if the thing it points to happens to be deleted, you don't want this object to be deleted too. In that case you can use `null=True` and `on_delete=models.SET_NULL` to implement a simple kind of [soft deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378331/physical-vs-logical-soft-delete-of-database-record).

Comment: This is a perfect answer, all possible combinations are explained in a very concise manner!

Answer (score 71):

You may have your answer however till this day it's difficult to judge whether to put `null=True` or `blank=True` or both to a field. I personally think it's pretty useless and confusing to provide so many options to developers. Let the handle the nulls or blanks however they want.

I follow this table, from [*Two Scoops of Django*](https://twoscoopspress.com/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-11): [image]

[image: Table showing when to use null or blank for each field type]

Comment: FYI, `NullBooleanField` is deprecated since Django 3.1 in favor of `BooleanField(null=True)`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#nullbooleanfield

Answer (score 63):

As said in Django Model Field reference: [Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/)

> ### Field options
>
> *The following arguments are available to all field types. All are optional.*
>
> #### `null`
>
> `Field.null`
>  If `True`, Django will store empty values as `NULL` in the database. Default is `False`.
>
> Avoid using `null` on string-based fields such as `CharField` and
>   `TextField` because empty string values will always be stored as empty
>   strings, not as `NULL`. If a string-based field has `null=True`, that
>   means it has two possible values for "no data": `NULL`, and the empty
>   string. In most cases, it’s redundant to have two possible values for
>   "no data"; the Django convention is to use the empty string, not
>   `NULL`.
>
> For both string-based and non-string-based fields, you will also need
>   to set `blank=True` if you wish to permit empty values in forms, as
>   the `null` parameter only affects database storage (see `blank`).
>
> > **Note**
> >
> > When using the Oracle database backend, the value NULL will be stored to denote the empty string regardless of this attribute
>
> #### `blank`
>
> `Field.blank`
>
> If `True`, the field is allowed to be blank. Default is `False`.
>
> Note that this is different than `null`. `null` is purely
>   database-related, whereas `blank` is validation-related. If a field
>   has `blank=True`, form validation will allow entry of an empty value.
>   If a field has `blank=False`, the field will be required.

Answer (score 34):

Simply `null=True` defines database should accept `NULL` values, on other hand `blank=True` defines on form validation this field should accept blank values or not(If `blank=True` it accept form without a value in that field and `blank=False`[default value] on form validation it will show **This field is required** error.

`null=True/False` related to database

`blank=True/False` related to form validation

Answer (score 24):

Here is an example of the field with `blank= True` and `null=True`

```
description = models.TextField(blank=True, null= True)
```

In this case:
`blank = True`: tells our form that it is ok to leave the description field blank

and

`null = True`: tells our database that it is ok to record a null value in our db field and not give an error.

Answer (score 12):

If you set `null=True`, it will allow the value of your database column to be set as `NULL`. If you only set `blank=True`, django will set the default new value for the column equal to `""`.

There's one point where `null=True` would be necessary even on a `CharField` or `TextField` and that is when the database has the **`unique`** flag set for the column. In this case you'll need to use this:

```
a_unique_string = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
```

Preferrably skip the `null=True` for **non-unique** `CharField` or `TextField`. Otherwise some fields will be set as `NULL` while others as `""` , and you'll have to check the field value for `NULL` everytime.

Comment: Surprisingly the only answer that has it correct why NULL is important.

Answer (score 9):

The default values of ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍`null` and blank are `False`.

`Null`: It is database-related. Defines if a given database column will accept null values or not.

`Blank`: It is validation-related. It will be used during forms validation, when calling `form.is_valid()`.

That being said, it is perfectly fine to have a field with `null=True` and `blank=False`. Meaning on the database level the field can be `NULL`, but in the application level it is a required field.

Now, where most developers get it wrong: Defining `null=True` for string-based fields such as `CharField` and `TextField`. Avoid doing that. Otherwise, you will end up having two possible values for “no data”, that is: **`None`** and an empty string. Having two possible values for “no data” is redundant. The Django convention is to use the empty string, not `NULL`.

Answer (score 8):

```
null = True
```

Means there is no constraint of database for the field to be filled, so you can have an object with null value for the filled that has this option.

```
blank = True
```

Means there is no constraint of validation in django forms. so when you fill a `modelForm` for this model you can leave field with this option unfilled.

Answer (score 7):

Here, is the main difference of `null=True` and `blank=True`:

The default value of both `null` and `blank` is False. Both of these values work at field level i.e., whether we want to keep a field `null` or `blank`.

`null=True` will set the field’s value to `NULL` i.e., no data. It is basically for the databases column value.

```
date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

`blank=True` determines whether the field will be required in forms. This includes the admin and your own custom forms.

`title = models.CharField(blank=True) // title can be kept blank.`
 In the database `("")` will be stored.
`null=True` `blank=True` This means that the field is optional in all circumstances.

```
epic = models.ForeignKey(null=True, blank=True)
// The exception is CharFields() and TextFields(), which in Django are never saved as NULL. Blank values a
```

Answer (score 6):

When we save anything in Django admin two steps validation happens, on Django level and on Database level. We can't save text in a number field.

Database has data type `NULL`, it's nothing. When Django creates columns in the database it specifies that they can't be empty. And if you will try to save `NULL` you will get the database error.

Also on Django-Admin level, all fields are required by default, you can't save blank field, Django will throw you an error.

So, if you want to save blank field you need to allow it on Django and Database level.
**`blank=True`** - will allow empty field in admin panel
**`null=True`** - will allow saving `NULL` to the database column.

Answer (score 6):

#### `null = True || blank = True || null = True && blank = True`

```py
class TestModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)   # it's not a correct way
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

#### THE DB FIELDS FOR: `MySQL`

```sql
CREATE TABLE TestModel (
     `id`        INT(10)        NOT     NULL      AUTO_INCREMENT,

     `field1`    VARCHAR(100)   NULL    DEFAULT   NULL,
     `field2`    VARCHAR(100)   NOT     NULL,
     `field3`    VARCHAR(100)   NULL    DEFAULT   NULL,
)
```

##### case-01: `null = True`

```
db:   db   field is accepts null value
form: form field is `required`

NB: DB IS ACCEPTS NULL VALUE, BUT FORM FIELD IS REQUIRED. SO FORM IS 
SUBMITTED WHEN THIS FIELD HAVE SOME VALUE. it's good.
```

##### case-02: `blank = True`

```
db:   db   field is not accepts null value
form: form field is `optional`

NB: FORM IS VALID WITHOUT ANY VALUE, BUT DB IS NOT ACCEPTS NULL VALUE.
SO THE FORM IS SUBMITTED WITHOUT ANY VALUE THEN BOOM. it's worst.
```

##### case-03: `null = True && blank = True`

```
db:   db   field is accepts null value
form: form field is `optional`

NB: HERE FORM FIELD IS OPTIONAL & FORM IS VALID WITHOUT ANY VALUE 
& DB ALSO ACCEPTS NULL VALUE. SO, IT'S BEST TO USE `null=True && blank=True`
```

##### :)

Answer (score 4):

**null** is for database and **blank** is for fields validation that you want to show on user interface like textfield to get the last name of person.
If **lastname=models.charfield (blank=true)** it didnot ask user to enter last name as this is the optional field now.
If **lastname=models.charfield (null=true)**  then it means that if this field doesnot get any value from user then it will store in database as an empty string " ".

Answer (score 4):

Here is its answer in simple words:-

By `null = True` we are telling the **database** that this field of the model could be NULL, by `blank = True` we are telling **Django** that this field of the model could be NULL

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer would be: Null is for Database tables while Blank is for Django Forms.

Answer (score 3):

Null is purely database-related, whereas blank is validation-related. If a field has blank=True , validation on Django's admin site will allow entry of an empty value. If a field has blank=False , the field will be required

Answer (score 3):

```
Blank=False # this field is required.
Null=False # this field should not be null

Blank=True # this field is optional.
Null=True # Django uses empty string (''), not NULL.
```

**Note:**
Avoid using `null=True` on string-based fields such as `CharField` and `TextField` and `FileField`/`ImageField`.

Ref: [Django null](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#null) , [Django blank](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#blank)

Answer (score 2):

**In Very simple words**,

Blank is different than null.

**null** is **purely database-related**, whereas **blank is validation-related(required in form)**.

If `null=True`, Django will `store empty values as NULL in the database`. If a field has `blank=True`, form validation will `allow entry of an empty value`. If a field has blank=False, the field will be required.

Answer (score 2):

`null=True` and `blank=True` are fields attributes in django.db.models. null is database related while blank is validation related.

### null

The default is `null=False`. If null=False, Django will not allow NULL values in the database column.

If `null=True`, Django will store empty values as NULL in the database column.  For CharField and TextField, django will use empty string '' instead of NULL. Avoid using null attribute for CharField and TextField. One exception is when CharField has `unique=True` and `blank=True`, then `null=True` is required.

### blank

The default is `blank=False`. If blank=False, the field will be required.

If `blank=True`, the field is optional and can be left blank. blank=True with null=False will require implementing clean() on model to programmatically set any missing values.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, null is truly database related. If null=true, DB will store null inputs as null. Otherwise, empty strings are stored as empty strings.
Whereas, if blank=true, form will validate it as ok, else the field will be considered 'required' by form.

Both are by default false.

Comment: Even if null=False you can store empty string in CharField ('') if null= True you can store None value or empty string ''

Answer (score 1):

null - default is False 
       if True, Django will store empty as null in the database.

blank - default is False
        if true that field is allowed to be blank

more, goto
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/

Answer (score 1):

This table below demonstrates the main differences:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Purpose                  | null=True        | blank = True         |
|--------------------------|------------------|----------------------|
| Field can be empty in DB | Do this          | Unaffected           |
|--------------------------|------------------|----------------------|
| ModelForm(required field)| Unaffected       | field not required   |
|--------------------------|------------------|----------------------|
| Form Validation          | Unaffected       | field not required   |
|--------------------------|------------------|----------------------|
| on_delete=SET_NULL       | Need this        | Unaffected           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

**The meaning of null=True and blank=True in the model also depends on how these fields were defined in the form class.**

Suppose you have defined the following class:

```
class Client (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField (max_length=100, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField (max_length=100, blank=False)
```

If the form class has been defined like this:

```
class ClientForm (ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ['name', 'address']
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput (attrs = {'class': 'form-control form-control-sm'}),
            'address': forms.TextInput (attrs = {'class': 'form-control form-control-sm'})
        }
```

Then, the 'name' field will not be mandatory (due to the blank=True in the model) and the 'address' field will be mandatory (due to the blank=False in the model).

However, if the ClientForm class has been defined like this:

```
class ClientForm (ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ['name', 'address']

    name = forms.CharField (
        widget = forms.TextInput (attrs = {'class': 'form-control form-control-sm'}),
    )
    address = forms.CharField (
        widget = forms.TextInput (attrs = {'class': 'form-control form-control-sm'}),
    )
```

Then, both fields ('name' and 'address') will be mandatory, **"since fields defined declaratively are left as-is"** (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/), i.e. the default for the 'required' attribute of the form field is True and this will require that the fields 'name' and 'address' are filled, even if, in the model, the field has been set to blank=True.

Answer (score 1):

`blank=True` can be set to any model field to control whether that field can be left empty when entering a value in a form. Here, we are talking about entering data.

`null=True`, if we set `blank=True` for a field, that model field does not receive any value, then the database or Django has to do something with that field when data is written into the database. For any kind of text content an empty string is stored in the database, so there is a value stored in the database. For other kinds of fields like date fields or numbers, we use the special data type "null". "null" can be used if a field potentially has no value, but by default, Django does not allow "null" values. That is why you need to explicitly set `null=True`.

Let's say you set `blank=True`, for any non-text fields, but you did not specify "null=True", Django will not know what to store and it would throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding the difference between `null` and `blank` in Django is crucial for beginners, as it affects both database integrity and how forms validate data.

****Here's a table summarising their key differences and uses:****

[image]

Let me explain it in detail with possible advantages & disadvantages.

**1. When only `null=True`**

Allows storing `NULL` values in the database. It's a database schema-related setting.

***Advantages:*** This provides flexibility in database design for non-string fields, allowing "no data" to be explicitly stored.

***Disadvantages:*** For string fields, can lead to a mix of `NULL` and empty strings for "no data", which is inconsistent also this does not affect the form validation, the field will still be required on forms.

**2. When only `blank=True`**

Allows the field to be left blank in the forms. It's related to validation in Django forms and the admin interface. This is applicable to all field types, it makes a field optional in forms.

***Advantages:*** Enhances user experience by not requiring input in forms for optional fields.

***Disadvantages:*** When used with non-string fields, `blank=True` without `null=True` can lead to `IntegrityError` upon form submission, as the database expects a value. Also, it does not alter the database schema, so the database layer still expects data.

**3. When `null=True` and `blank=True`**

Allows NULL values in the database and makes the field optional in forms.

***Advantages:*** This combination offers the greatest flexibility, allowing fields to be optional in both database and form contexts. It's particularly beneficial for non-string fields where a lack of data is best represented by `NULL`.

***Disadvantages:*** For string fields, combining `null=True` and `blank=True` is generally discouraged to prevent a mix of `NULL` and empty strings in the database, which can lead to inconsistencies in data representation.

Answer (score 1):

In django, null=True related to the database schema, allowing for NULL values in the database, while blank=True is related to form validation, enabling fields to be left empty in form submissions.

Comment: This si all very well examined here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8609425/12846804. You would have to make it clear what your answer adds to it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35632899)

Answer (score 0):

When you set `null=true` it will set `null` in your database if the field is not filled. If
you set `blank=true` it will not set any value to the field.

Answer (score 0):

When you say null=False, it means a data must be pass to the database to be saved. When you say blank=False it means a data must be inputed from your frontend and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

Each option in the Django model serves two purposes

1. Defining field constraints at the Database level (e.g SQL, Postgresql, or any other)
2. Defining field constraints at the Form level ( At the framework level that is above the database layer)

Now Let's get back to `null` and `blank`

- `blank` is Django forms related. It is used for validation of Django forms, in admin or Django. Specifically when we call `form.is_valid()`
- `null` is database-related. It tells the underlying database whether the column would allow `null` value to be saved or not.

For example, let's see the below example-

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    website = models.UrlField()
    founded_on = models.DateField(blank=True, null=False)
    random_date = models.DateFeild(blank=False, null=True)
    random_text = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I have defined a `Company` model which has 2 fields where we are playing around with `blank` and `null` options. Let's see what happens with the different fields

- `founded_on`: can receive an empty `string` value at form level (framework/language level). While saving to the database then we would raise `IntegrityError` because the Database will not accept the `null` value due to `null` being `false`.
- `random_date`: receiving an empty value at form level (Framework) through validation error, since blank is not allowed due to `blank` true that is setting constraints at the form level. However, it also allows the column to be `null` at the database layer.
- `random_text`: This is the option that means that the field is allowed to be saved as `null` at the database layer and also empty `string` value is allowed to be valid data as per the Django forms validation logic due to `blank=True`. So in short it can receive empty values (at the framework level and can store empty value at DB level.

To resolve all this confusion consider your Database commit as two layer procedure.

- First, it fill out the form where we can call validate data at the Framework level.
- Second, It has a database-level option that helps in defining DB constraints.

Here `blank` is the framework level thing while `null` is database level contraint.