# ForeignKey does not allow null values

Tags: django-rest-framework, model, foreign-keys, serialization

I am using the Django REST Framework 2.0.

Here is my model class:

```
class Mission(models.Model):
  assigned_to = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',
                                   related_name='missions_assigned',
                                   blank = True)
```

Here is my view class:

```
class MissionList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Mission
    serialize_class = MissionSerializer
```

1. The multipart form is rendered in the browser with empty choice for `assigned_to` field.
2. When posting raw JSON, I get the following error message:

`Cannot assign None: "Mission.assigned_to" does not allow null values.`

Answer (score 158, accepted):

The `blank` option is used in the form validation, and the `null` is used when writing to database.

So you might add `null=True` to that field.

**EDIT:** continue the comment

Considering the two steps when saving object:

1. Validator(controlled by `blank`)
2. Database limitation(controlled by `null`)

For `default` option, take `IntegerField` for example,
`default=5, blank=True, null=False`, pass (1) even if you didn't assign a value(having `blank=True`), pass (2) because it has a default value(5) and writes `5` instead of `None` to DB.
`blank=True, null=False`, which pass (1) but not (2), because it attempts to write `None` to DB.

Thus, if you want to make a field optional, use either `default=SOMETHING, blank=True, null=False` or `blank=True, null=True`.

Another exception is the string-like field, such as `CharField`.
It's suggested that use the `blank=True` **alone**, leaving `null=False` behind.
This makes a field either a string(>=1 char(s)) or a empty string('', with len()==0), and never `None`.

The reason is that when `null=True` is set, there will be two possible value for the state "unset": empty string and `None`, which is confusing(and might causing bugs).

Comment: Which means `blank = True` must always be used with `null = True`? Why can't I choose empty in my form? I did use `blank = True`.

Comment: `assigned_to==None` passed the form validator, but not database.
Without `null=True`, you cannot write `None` into database.

Thus, generally, if you want an optional field, set both `blank` and `null` to `True`.

Comment: However, there're two exceptions, `default` option and string-like fields.

(I'd like to add after the post, instead of here, the comment.)

Comment: I'd just like to point out that `null` can also affect behaviour behind DB restrictions (see https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12708)

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609192/differentiate-null-true-blank-true-in-django) will be helpful for `blank and null`

Comment: The default=SOMETHING is what I was missing

Answer (score 27):

ForeignKey allows null values if this behavior was set.
Your code will look like this:

```
class Mission(models.Model):
    assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        related_name='missions_assigned',
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
```

You have to write **`null=True`**.

Note: after you change a model, you need to run `python manage.py makemigrations yourappname` and then `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: When updating existing model it will result in error. There are some ways to get through it, the simpliest is to delete existing database. 
See example solution there:https://coderbook.com/@marcus/add-new-non-null-foreign-key-to-existing-django-model/

Comment: @JakubJabłoński can you elaborate on why it will result in an error? Making a `ForeignKey` nullable and migrating is a common operation and should not give any error. I do that all the time.

Comment: @JakubJabłoński You might be thinking of this for the reverse case, moving a model from "null is allowed" to "must have a value", in which case adding a manual migration to provide default values or starting from scratch, as you suggested, would be a solution. The solution discussed above, though, has no problem.

Answer (score 8):

The solution with changing the model and allowing for null with:

```
blank=True,
null=True
```

wasn't enough for me.

I was able to solve the issue by setting required in the serializer to false, e.g.

```
field = MyModelSerializer(required=False)
```

as described [here (Django ForeignKey field required despite blank=True and null=True)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40237969/django-foreignkey-field-required-despite-blank-true-and-null-true).

I ended up doing both. Allowing for null with `blank=True, null=True` in the model and not requiring the field in the serializer by `required=False`

Comment: this answer needs more upvotes. Saved me hours.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, `required=False` wasn't enough. I needed `allow_null` in the serializer, [per Django ForeignKey field required despite blank=True and null=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606115/django-rest-framework-nested-serializer-required-false-error).