# Django ForeignKey field required despite blank=True and null=True

Tags: python, json, django, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I am using Django REST Framework and I have a `MyNodel` with a related `MyOtherModel` in a many-to-one relationship:

```
models.ForeignKey(MyModel, related_name="my_other_models", blank=True, null=True)
```

Although `blank=True, null=True`, when I try to post a `MyModel` JSON without a `my_other_models` field I get a "this field is required" error.

Comment: It would be much easier for us to help you if you provide the traceback and the view where you try to create MyNodel object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your serializer, you need to add `required=False`.

```
field = MyModelSerializer(required=False)
```

Comment: What should be done if using `class Meta` to define the fields automatically ?

Comment: Just overwrite it with this new field.