# HTML&Django-why still get error message for null input for class field models.DateField(null=True)?

Tags: html, django

I have a date data type in one of my class and it is optional, so I set null=True. but when the user input nothing for the date and submit the info, I get the error message of

> [u"'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD
>   format."]

Field :`birthday=models.DateField(null=True)`

HTML code is as below.

`<div>
            <label>Birthday:</label>
            <input type="date" id="id_bd" name="bd">
        </div>`

Can anyone explain to me why this would happen and how am I going to handle this null input error? Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [differentiate null=True, blank=True in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609192/differentiate-null-true-blank-true-in-django)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609192/differentiate-null-true-blank-true-in-django), but the short version is `null=True` defines what happens in the database it sets the default value to `NULL`, and `blank=True` defines if the form field is required or not.