# IntegrityError in Django

Tags: python, django

I added A Many2Many field in one of my forms and now I am getting an IntegrityError on submit. The exact error text is

> IntegrityError at /add_person/ hireterm_person.mail_lists may not be NULL

It worked fine until I added the new field. When I look at the POST data on the debug change, I see it being passed, so I don't know where the break occurs.

Models

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Mailists(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)

class Person(models.Model):
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        ('Mrkt', 'Marketing'),
        ('Fin/Off', 'Finance / Office'),
        ('Care', 'Care'),
        ('Sales', 'Sales'),
        )
    ROLE_TYPE = (
        ('Full', 'Full Time'),
        ('Part', 'Part Time'), 
        ('Intern', 'Intern'),
        )

    first_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_start = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = "", choices = ROLE_CHOICES)
    manager = models.ForeignKey('self', limit_choices_to = {'is_manager': True}, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    role_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = "", choices = ROLE_TYPE)
    laptop_needed = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    phone_needed = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    desk_loco = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    mail_lists = models.ManyToManyField(Mailists, blank=True)
    notes = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=500)
    is_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class PersonForm(ModelForm):
    mail_lists = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Mailists.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Person
```

**EDIT**

I added mail_lists = request.POST.getlist('mail_lists'). When I add a print to this, the list returned is all of the check boxes, put the POST data is still a single string, the last box checked.

Views

```
from hireterm.models import Person, Mailists, PersonForm
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.template import Context, loader
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.core.mail import send_mail

@login_required
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'hireterm/home.html')

def add_person(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        mail_lists = request.POST.getlist('mail_lists') 
        person_form = PersonForm(request.POST)
        if person_form.is_valid(): 
            person_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/new_hire') # Redirect after POST

    else:
        person_form = PersonForm() # An unbound form

    return render(request, 'hireterm/additem.html', {
        'form': person_form,
    })
```

Comment: I believe the issue is I am not returning a list. The post data I get, no matter how many boxes are checked, is the number of the last box checked in unicode, eg u'3'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On your field:

```
mail_lists = models.ManyToManyField(Mailists, blank=True)
```

you have added `blank=True` to the field, but not `null=True`. This means that your DB is expecting that field to have a value. So when it doesn't you get an error.

**[null](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null)**

> If True, Django will store empty values as NULL in the database. Default is False.
> Note that empty string values will always get stored as empty strings, not as NULL. Only use null=True for non-string fields such as integers, booleans and dates. For both types of fields, you will also need to set blank=True if you wish to permit empty values in forms, as the null parameter only affects database storage (see blank).

**[blank](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#blank)**

> If True, the field is allowed to be blank. Default is False.
>
> Note that this is different than null. null is purely database-related, whereas blank is validation-related. If a field has blank=True, form validation will allow entry of an empty value. If a field has blank=False, the field will be required.

Here are some other explanations:

- [differentiate null=True, blank=True in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609192/differentiate-null-true-blank-true-in-django)
- http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/28/django-tips-difference-between-blank-and-null/

Comment: I get the error when I have a checkbox checked off, which I assume to not be null.

Comment: Also, that is after I added null=True to mail_lists

Comment: Did you migrate the DB after adding `null=True`?

Comment: Or if you're in dev, just need to syncdb again. Btw, "a checkbox checked off" doesn't get sent along with the request (so its value is `null`, check that with pdb or inspect your `request.POST` dict), which is not what `blank=True` field expects (at least a blank value)

Comment: I am in dev. I did sync the db after adding it, I ran validate, sql hireterm, syncdb. I still get the same error.

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo I have checked the contents of the dict, and if I check of say, the first and third checkboxes, the dict contains a list of those. SO I can't figure out why this is returning a null value