# Validate POST data with extra argument using Django modelForm

Tags: python, django

I have this model:

```
class SearchPreference(models.Model):
    """Saves the preferred location and school_type of the User
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='search_preference')
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True)
    school_type = models.ForeignKey(SchoolType, null=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'grants'
```

and this form:

```
class SearchPreferenceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    location = forms.ChoiceField(queryset=Location.objects.all(),
                                 to_field_name='slug',
                                 required=False)
    school_type = forms.ChoiceField(queryset=SchoolType.objects.all(),
                                    to_field_name='slug',
                                    required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = SearchPreference
        fields = ('location', 'school_type')
```

I am trying to use the form to do validation of POST data, I am not displaying it in a template.

The problem is, the POST data can include a value which isn't in the Location or SchoolType table, so the form doesn't validate. The value is 'all', signifying 'all locations' or 'all school types', and I really want this to be saved as a SearchPreference with no location, i.e. location = null.

I could change 'all' to an empty value and that might work but then validation/logic has moved out of the form.

I thought I could use empty_value = 'all' but this doesn't work on a modelChoiceField.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: You want one more field in your form that is a choices field of those values?

Comment: No, I want either field to accept the value 'all' as null, i.e. when data = {'location':'all'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked in the end:

```
class SearchPreferenceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SearchPreferenceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['location'].empty_values.append('all')
        self.fields['school_type'].empty_values.append('all')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your model needs `blank=True` as well and `null=True`

```
location = models.ForeignKey(Location, blank=True, null=True)
school_type = models.ForeignKey(SchoolType, blank=True, null=True)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609192/differentiate-null-true-blank-true-in-django) post talks about blank and null.

Comment: This still doesn't work:

>>> form.errors
{'school_type': [u'Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.'], 'location': [u'Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}

Comment: you need to set 'empty_label' to "all" not `empty_values`