# Model field blank=false doesn't work when field is readonly in admin.py

Tags: python, django, forms, django-admin, dry

I have a field in one of the models like :

```
field = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
```

in admin.py I have

```
readonly_fields = ('field',)
```

When I try to save it from the admin, it does not throw a validation error which is quite sane.

But if I try to do this in my `views.py` ,

```
form = MyForm(#some data here from request.POST)
print form.is_valid()
```

I get error saying :

```
'this field is required'
```

Here `MyForm` is a `ModelForm` for that model. I am trying to create another form to replace the admin form so that my team can use the new form that I have created instead of the admin.

I want to run that form through `ModelForm` that I have already written and I don't want to repeat code and re-write validation.

Why is this behavior different between admin form and any other form ? 
Is saying `blank=True` in my models the only way to make this work ?

Comment: if your field is read-only try to exclude it in your modelform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways in which you can solve this. In your `ModelForm`:

1. either exclude that field.
2. or set it to `required=False`.

**Way #1:**

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = MyModel
    exclude = ['field']
```

**Way #2:**

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = MyModel

    field = forms.Charfield(required=False)
```

**Which way is better?**

If you do not want that `field` to be editable, you should go with *way #1*. But if you want this field to be editable but not *required*, go with *way #2*.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609192/differentiate-null-true-blank-true-in-django).

**From the accepted answer**

`null=True` sets `NULL` (versus `NOT NULL`) on the column in your DB. Blank values for Django field types such as DateTimeField or ForeignKey will be stored as `NULL` in the DB.

`blank=True` determines whether the field will be required in forms. This includes the admin and your own custom forms. If blank=True then the field will not be required, whereas if it's False the field cannot be blank.

**In addition**

From [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields)

readonly_fields will be excluded in ModelForm used for creating and editing in the admin.

**Update**

As for solving your problem, you can exclude it in your modelform or set the field to required=False. More on that here [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/).