# Discard saving of model on admin panel

Tags: python, django, forms, model, admin

I have model(model.py):

```
class Group(models.Model):
    system_id = models.ForeignKey(System)
    group_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    description = models.TextField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    latintitle = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    audio = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

And i've added custom field for upload file with many groups and then parse it(admin.py):

```
class GroupModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    file = forms.FileField(required=False)
    def save(self, commit=True):
        file = self.cleaned_data['file']
        if file:
            lines = file.readlines()

        # ...do something with extra_field here...
        return super(GroupModelForm, self).save(commit=commit)
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields =  ('file',)

class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'title', 'group_id')
    form = GroupModelForm
    fieldsets = (
                 ('New Group', {
                  'fields': ('system_id', 'group_id', 'title', 'latintitle', 'description', 'audio')
                  }),
                 ('Upload JSON file with groups info', {
                  'fields': ('file',)
                  }),
                 )
```

When I'm uploading file it says other fields needs to be filled.

**My question**: How to ignore those errors and after processing of file redirect to another page?

[image]

**UPDATE:** I made all fields `blank=True`, except one

Comment: Did you set the fields as `null=True` as well?

Comment: @Railslide I was need it only for case when I want to upload json with many data. In admin.py I overwrote the saving function for validating the data from fields.

Comment: @Railslide you was right! for most fileds it no need, but for ForeignKey it's needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your fields as `null=True` as well, since you need to allow `NULL` in the database in order to allow blank fields in forms.

About the difference between `blank=True` and `null=True` and how they interact with forms and fields, here's a very clear explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8609425/2926113