# in models.py, I set IntegerField blank=True, but in actual, this field also must be not null

Tags: python, django

in models.py, I set ComissionRate field IntegerField blank=True, but in actual, this ComissionRate field also must be not null

```
class System(models.Model):         
    BulletinBoardContent = models.CharField(max_length=64,blank=True)   
    BulletinBoardDescription = models.TextField(blank=True)  
    BulletinBoardDate = models.DateField(blank=True)  
    ComissionRate = models.FloatField(blank=True)
```

when I insert a new system item, if I don't fill ComissionRate, there will have an error
as follows:
        Exception Type: IntegrityError
        Exception Value: system_system.ComissionRate may not be NULL

PS：DateField has the same situations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [differentiate null=True, blank=True in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609192/differentiate-null-true-blank-true-in-django)

Comment: Thank you. But I had tried. It is still not work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. That is [clearly documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#blank):

> Note that this is different than `null`. `null` is purely database-related, whereas `blank` is validation-related. If a field has `blank=True`, form validation will allow entry of an empty value. If a field has `blank=False`, the field will be required.

Answer (score 0):

Two most common options for a blank field in your model are:

- **(blank=True)** if the field is CharField or TextField (or any other string fields)
- **(blank=True, null=True)** for other fields: FloatField, IntegerField, DateField etc.

Databases can accept a blank (empty) string, but there's no "blank date" or "blank integer". You must use a special SQL [NULL marker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)) indicating that a non-string field is blank.