# Django: Asymmetric ManyToMany Relation

Tags: python, django, database-design

I am new to using `django` and would appreciate your input to the following problem.

Two models are present, namely `A` and `B`. Instances of `A` must belong to at least one instance of `B`, while a `B` could contain any number of instances of `A`s from 0 to infinite.

```
class A(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
  created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
  modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

class B(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
  created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
  modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
  A_list = models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

Okay. I think, based on the description I have given, `ManyToManyField` should be used for the two models. The thing is, from what I have read, `blank = false` must be used to prevent a `null` assignment for `A` (since an `A` must be assigned to at least one `B`) but a `B` may not have an assigned `A` (and thus should not have the `blank = false` statement. Could anyone asymmetric `ManyToMany` relation can be implemented in `django` `Model`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place the ManyToManyField in A, with `null=False`, and `blank=False` (default, you got this right). This way, you can create B instances with no problems, even when there are no existing A instances.

When you create an instance of A, `blank=False` makes sure the B_list field is required. The `null=False` makes sure the database will not allow `NULL` values.

Your code would become:

```
class A(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
  created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
  modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)      
  B_list = models.ManyToManyField('B')

class B(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
  created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
  modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

For the difference between `null` and `blank` in Django, see this post:

[differentiate null=True, blank=True in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609192/differentiate-null-true-blank-true-in-django)

Comment: I understand the logic. So should there be ```blank = False``` in ```B_list = models.ManyToManyField('B')```, or should it not? Also, from what I have read, the argument to ```ManyToManyField``` was the pointer to the class, not a string value, in this case ```'B'``` in ```ManyToManyField('B')```. Is there something that I am missing or is that a typo?

Comment: To your first question, no you don't need `blank = False` since this is the default. You could put it in there, but it wouldn't change anything. The string value is needed here because your A model is defined above your B model. At that point in the code, the B model does not exist yet, and the string parameter makes sure it is evaluated when all the models are ready. You could also switch them around (put `A` below `B` and simply say `ManyToManyField(B)`)

Comment: It did not occur to me the ordering in Python code was relevant. I ended up switching the order of the two classes last night. Thank you.