# django: Required Field Not Having The "required" Attribute in HTML

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-floppyforms

I am new to django and I think it is fantastic so far. I faced this weird issue today:
I have this FormModel:

```
class RegisterForm2(UserCreationForm):
    mobile2 = forms.CharField(
        label=_('Mobile Confirmation'),
        max_length=50,
        required=True,
        widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'nocopy'})
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'mobile', 'mobile2', 'guardian_mobile']
        labels = {
            'username': _('Government ID'),
        }
        widgets = {
            # workaround since __init__ setting to required doesnt work
            'mobile': forms.TextInput(attrs = {'required':''}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterForm2, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['mobile'].required = True
```

Now mobile field has *blank=True* in the model but i want it to be required in the form only and so I did that in the **__init__** . Now it is making the field required but it is not adding **required=""** to the text input. Now if i have overridden the field (and added the **required=True**) like I did **mobile2** field I wouldn't have this issue.  This is a an issue because if i want the attribute required to show on fields i have to override the fields in the form to add the **required=True** which will go against the *DRY* principle. Am I missing something or is this a bug of some sort?

**Edit:**
I failed to mention that I am using floppy forms. It could be related to that. I have to investigate this issue further.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [differentiate null=True, blank=True in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609192/differentiate-null-true-blank-true-in-django)

Comment: That is exactly what `blank` is used for

Comment: @Sayse I wanted to leave model field as blank=True but enforce required=True from the modelform without overriding the definition for the whole field. I was able to do that from the __init__ but the field shows without the "required" HTML attribute.

Comment: Oh so you're looking for client side validation rather than the server side? Alasdairs answer covers that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note this answer assumes you are using regular Django forms, I wrote it before you mentioned that you were using floppy forms.**

Django does not currently add the `required` HTML 5 attribute when it renders form fields. Overriding the widget for the `mobile` field sounds looks OK to me. You are changing the widget, not duplicating the field, so I don't think you need to worry about it being DRY.

Note that setting required in the `__init__` is having an effect - if you submit the form with an empty value for `mobile`, then you will get a validation error. Your `mobile2` field will not have `required` in the rendered HTML unless you add it to its widget attrs.

Django will add the `required` attribute to form fields in Django 1.10, see [ticket #22383](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22383).

Comment: i am using django 1.95 and in it adds required attribute in HTML for mobile2 although i didnt add it in the widget attrs. django will add the attribute required only if u redefine the field again in the form (not DRY) and specify required=True.

Comment: *it adds the required attribute in HTML for mobile2* -- That's not the behaviour I see in Django 1.9, or expect by looking at the code/ticket. Maybe you are rendering the fields in some custom way that you haven't told us about (e.g. using crispy forms).

Comment: could it be related to floppy forms? I failed to mention that

Comment: If you're using floppy-forms them you'll see different behaviour. [It does include the required attribute](http://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/differences.html#required-attribute).

Answer (score 1):

This is actuially possible in your `__init__`. You just have to add the required attribute to the widget attributes:

`def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterForm2, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['mobile'].required = True
        self.fields['mobile'].widget.attrs['required'] = 'required'`

Answer (score 0):

> but i want it to be required in the form only

```
'mobile': forms.TextInput(attrs = {'required':''}),
```

You can do this in views.py also. That's how I prefer to do it.

```
form.fields['mobile'].widget.attrs['required'] = True
```