# Django (1.9) makemigrations doesn't get Blank=True on boolean field

Tags: python, django, database, model

I have the following model:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    """
    Model for a site entry
    @author: Leonardo Pessoa
    @since: 05/09/2016 
    """
    from decimal import Decimal

    consolidated_financials     = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    type                        = models.ForeignKey(Type)
    tier1_business              = models.ForeignKey(Business, limit_choices_to = {'tier': 1}, related_name='%(class)s_tier1')
```

Note that the `consolidated_financials` field has now the `blank=True` statement.
This was newly included. When I ran makemigrations, it didn't get the change, but when I add to `finance_manager_sso` it worked normally.

Is there a restriction with the Boolean field specifically?

Thanks

Comment: Related: [differentiate null=True, blank=True in django](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8609192/1324033)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`BooleanField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield) does not take null=True, instead, use [`NullBooleanField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#nullbooleanfield).

There is a [great answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/133617) on Programmers.se by Jacob Maristany that explains the reasoning behind this well

> By allowing nulls in a boolean field, you are turning an intended binary representation (true/false) into a tri-state representation (true, false, null) where your 'null' entries are indeterminate.

For the full discussion, see [Should I store False as Null in a boolean database field?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/133600)

Comment: Just to add to this, OP may be looking for `null=True`, if you're trying to allow a 'checked', 'unchecked', or 'unspecified' value.

Comment: BooleanField does not take null=True, instead, use NullBooleanField. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Huh, that's interesting. Good find! Anyone know the reason why a `BooleanField` couldn't/shouldn't work with `null=True`? Besides, of course, that the documentation says so. :)

Comment: Any change to the serialized field will create a migration, even if that change doesn't affect the database. This allows use of the field options at a specific point in the migration plan by e.g. a `RunPython` operation. You can easily test this with the `blank` parameter on e.g. an `IntegerField`, as the OP noticed as well.

Comment: @knbk - Yes I realised this myself too after answering (been a long day) although Im not able to delete my answer anymore, upvoted yours anyway

Comment: @knbk - I've now edited that out of my answer completely.

Answer (score 3):

The `blank` parameter is not used by `BooleanField`. Instead, it is [hard-coded](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fc3ac6573524acc58c23ae2c721c61bc9ed8c8d5/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L978) to `True`. Passing `blank=False` has no effect, so the migration autodetector doesn't detect any changes to the field, and doesn't create any migrations.

Since the `blank` parameter is used by `IntegerField`, passing in `blank=False` will lead to a change in the serialized field. The migration autodetector will detect that change and create a migration (even though that change doesn't affect the database).