# Django: model can be created without model field data?

Tags: django

This is my code:

```
class Order(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    merchant_uid = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    imp_uid = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    from_cart = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.merchant_uid
```

But strange thing is,

1. `Order.objects.create(user=request.user, from_cart=True)` works (in `views.py`).
2. `order = Order(user=request.user, from_cart=True)` and `order.save()` also works.

I didn't set `blank=True` and `null=True` on my `merchant_uid`, `imp_uid` fields, which means `required` field.

But how is it possible to create model without those field??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [differentiate null=True, blank=True in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609192/differentiate-null-true-blank-true-in-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are left empty. Because `null=False`, Django doesn't store empty values as `null` for these fields, and instead the database uses the empty string (`''`) for a varchar column that doesn't get a value.

`blank` is used for validation, e.g. when validating a ModelForm. It is not related to database constraints. You don't do any validation here, so it's not relevant.