# Django user first_name is not required but has NOT NULL constraint in database

Tags: django, database, postgresql

In my Django project I would like to have nullable User's first and last name. Django documentation say that `last_name` and `first_name` fields are optional. However when I want to insert values to `auth_user` table via SQL without `first_name` and `last_name` I got an error of not-null constraint

```
INSERT INTO 
auth_user(id, password, last_login, is_superuser, username, email, is_staff, is_active, date_joined)
VALUES 
(8, 'secret', null, false, 'user5', 'user@one.pl', false, true, current_date);

ERROR:  null value in column "first_name" violates not-null constraint
```

I am using:

- Django 1.10 (upgraded from django 1.9 during project development)
- Postgresql 9.6 (upgraded from pg 9.5 during project development)
- `django.contrib.auth.User`

By django admin site it is possible to create User without providing `first_name` and `last_name`.

Could you please help me to know why there is such a mismatch and how can I insert via SQL User with empty first and last name?

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using raw SQL for this rather than the Django ORM, out of curiosity?

It's not actually defined as NOT_NULL, it's defined as optional/blank when you're using the ORM (and consquently, forms).  It's defined as this in the library:

`first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)`

In other words, you can pass it as blank in forms, but it still has a `NOT_NULL` constraint.  If you were doing it in the ORM, you wouldn't notice this, as it defaults to an empty string, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609192/differentiate-null-true-blank-true-in-django).  So your options are either to pass it an empty string in your SQL query, or to use the ORM:

```
u = User.objects.create(your_stuff_here)
```

Comment: I am using raw SQL to prepare test data. We develop this project in a team so having the same test data is quite useful.

Comment: Sure, and that's broadly a great goal - you can do that through Django/python unittests too, though!  (Obviously there might be other reasons you want to do that in raw SQL depending on your team setup, etc., just worth pointing out. :) )

Comment: Basically, I tried before inserting an empty string too, but I made a mistake in SQL query, so it was not successful (`""` instead of `''`) 
Anyway, thanks for your answer

Comment: instead of raw sql for your test data, use fixtures and unittests to load the fixtures.