# Why Model field validation happens before validate or validate_<field> is called?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-validation

I just started learning Django Rest Framework and I can't understand **why DRF runs Model field validation before Own Validation** I have a model which has a URLField and basically all I want to add http:// or https:// before it validates, so wrote custom validation method

```
class ShortenerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        extra_kwargs = {
            'count': {'read_only':True}
        }
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'short_url', 'count', 'created_at')
        model = Shortener

    def validate_url(self, url):
        if not 'http://' in url and not 'https://' in url:
            url = 'http://' + url
        url_validate = URLValidator()
        try:
            url_validate(url)
        except:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Please Enter a Valid URL")
        return url
```

I even overide the **validate** method but again it is called after model field validation as it raises Exception. I guess i need to overide some method but no idea which one to override.

Answer (score 4):

You can override the is_valid method to avoid this behaviour

```
class ShortenerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def is_valid(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.initial_data.get('url'):
            # update self.initial_data with appended url

        return super(ShortenerSerializer, self).is_valid(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: i am getting This QueryDict instance is immutable. 
I did this.
`def run_validation(self, data):
   url = data.get('url')
   if url:
    if not 'http://' in url and not 'https://' in url:
        url = 'http://' + url
        data['url'] = url
        print(data)
   return super().run_validation(data)`

Comment: ah, got it. edited my answer to change the method names.

Comment: still getting the same QueryDict instance is immutable error. i am doing like this `self.initial_data['url'] = 'http://' + self.initial_data.get('url')`

Comment: Ah yes, that's exactly what I needed! This will trigger custom validators **before** calling Model  field validators!