# How to send null for Integerfield from form in DRF

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a simple model:

```
class TestRentalObject(models.Model):
some_field = models.TextField()

build_year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    validators=[MinValueValidator(1300), MaxValueValidator(2100)],
)
```

with ModelSerializer:

```
class TestRentObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = TestRentalObject

    fields = (
        "some_field",
        "build_year"
    )
```

And here is input field from form:

```
<input type="number" class="input-group__input input-group__input_no-require is-invalid" id="field-rent.build_year" placeholder="" name="rent.build_year">
```

When I keep this field empty, serializer sees it as invalid.

```
In [8]: data = {'some_field': 'some_text', 'build_year': ''}
In [9]: rs = TestRentObjectSerializer(data=data)
In [10]: rs.is_valid()
Out[10]: False
In [11]: rs.errors
Out[11]: {'build_year': [ErrorDetail(string='A valid integer is required.', code='invalid')]}
```

I believe the problem is that I get build_year as an empty string and not None. But how to do it correctly?

Comment: Try without "build_year" key, Like: 
`data = {'some_field': 'some_text'}`

Comment: @NeErAjKuMaR it works, but how to eliminate this field from the form if it's not filled?

Comment: It based on your frontend part, but you can also remove from Django with the condition if it's blank remove key from data dict.

Comment: @NeErAjKuMaR I see. Thanks, I thought there is a less patchy way to do it, cause it looks like a kind of popular scenario.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Post empty date field error with Django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46871046/post-empty-date-field-error-with-django-rest-framework)

Answer (score 0):

As NeErAj KuMaR recommended in comments I added a few lines into my view method.

```
    if request.data["rent"].get("build_year") == "":
        del request.data["rent"]["build_year"]

    serializer = TestRentObjectSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

It looks a bit patchy, but I didn't find better way to do this.