# Django, when using ForeignKey field, which is better blank=True or null=True?

Tags: django, foreign-keys

From: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.null

> Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and
>   TextField. If a string-based field has null=True, that means it has
>   two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty string. In most
>   cases, it’s redundant to have two possible values for “no data;” the
>   Django convention is to use the empty string, not NULL.

So What is better on ForeignKey Field? ForeignKey field is not string-based field, isn't it?

I wonder `what is convention for ForeignKey in django.`

null=True is better or blank=True is better?  In performance, convenience or somewhat anything.

Comment: You may refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609192/differentiate-null-true-blank-true-in-django?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's different. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#blank):

> Note that this is different than null. null is purely database-related, whereas blank is validation-related. If a field has blank=True, form validation will allow entry of an empty value. If a field has blank=False, the field will be required.

So for ForeignKey you need to set both: `null=True, blank=True`.

Answer (score 6):

These are used for different purposes:

- **Null = True**: It used if you want to make your column in the database as nullable
- **blank = True**: It does not effect in database column. This column still be not nullable (which is default), but in html form the input field can remain empty.