# Postgresql + Django : Not Null Fields Empty Value

Tags: django, postgresql

I know the title doesn't make any sense, but I just want to know how to insert an empty string or '' in a CharField made in Django? As far as I know by default, fields in Django are not nullable. Checking data in PGAdmin, I can see that most of the CharFields have '' as value. I wonder how is this possible? If I run

```
  cur_p.execute("""
                INSERT INTO "table"name" (address, school_address, sports ) VALUES ('', '', '')
```

I will get `psycopg2.IntegrityError: null value in column "created" violates not-null constraint`

Also I noticed that some fields have `blank=True` in them. Doesn't it contradict if you have a not nullable field then you declared `blank=True`?

Comment: please, give the code of CharField of your model.

Comment: `address = models.CharField(max_length=250)

school_adress = models.CharField(max_length=250)

sports = models.CharField(max_length=50)`

Comment: @tangoward add `null=True` to the fields you want to be able to set null, what does it matter if  you have two possible values? it's your desired outcome.

Comment: @tangoward if you really want to specific explanation of what `blank=True` and `null=True` does then go to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8609425/7707749

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#null), you can use `null=True` in your field definition to allow postgres to store null values for the column.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought but these fields are CharField. The documentation says `avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and TextField. If a string-based field has null=True, that means it has two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty string.`

Comment: I think this is the best explanation on my second question about having `blank=True` https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/07/25/django-tip-8-blank-or-null.html I still don't know how to insert an empty string in a `null=False` CharField