# object created even if field was required

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
#models.py

class Mymodel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False,blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100,null=False,blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=120,null=False,blank=False)
    email_notification = models.BooleanField()




#views.py

obj=MyModel.objects.create(name="ok",password="dsfdsfdsfdsfsfds",email_notification=1)
```

even if email was required field,then also object was created when I see in the admin panel.What can be the issue,Why object got created,even if email field was mandatory?
Also if I go in admin panel and open that object and click save then it raises that email is required

Comment: django version ??

Comment: django version is 2.0.4

Comment: email = models.EmailField(max_length=100,null=False,blank=False) it is not req.

Comment: @marin if this is not required why does it shows error on clicking save in django admin panel.Also, if  email = models.EmailField(max_length=100) is required,then same situation arised

Comment: please, upload the full error message.

Comment: actually there is no error,but there should be.Because in my model field is required but still object get created without populating that field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note: You don't to have provide null=False,blank=False in your fields because those are the values used by default.**(See the [Django `Field` `__int__`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L134) signature.).

```
def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, primary_key=False,
                 max_length=None, unique=False, blank=False, null=False,
                 db_index=False, rel=None, default=NOT_PROVIDED, editable=True,
                 serialize=True, unique_for_date=None, unique_for_month=None,
                 unique_for_year=None, choices=None, help_text='', db_column=None,
                 db_tablespace=None, auto_created=False, validators=(),
                 error_messages=None):
```

By default all the fields in database are created with `NOT NULL` constraint. **If you set `null=True` for a particular field, then django sets `NULL` on the column in your DB.** **It’s the database equivalent of Python’s `None` keyword.**

***Example with `null` argument***

Assume that I have the following `Mymodel` in my `my_app` and I set `email` field to `null=True`.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    email_notification = models.BooleanField()
```

In Shell,

```
>> from my_app.models import MyModel

>> new = MyModel.objects.create(name="ok",
                                password="dsfdsfdsfdsfsfds",
                                email_notification=1)
>> new.email == None
>> True # As you can see Django sets db value 
        # as NULL and when we query the data it converts back to Python `None` object.
```

***Example without `null` argument***

Assume that I have the following `Mymodel` in my `my_app`.(remember `null` will be `False` by default)

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    email_notification = models.BooleanField()
```

In Shell,

```
>> from my_app.models import MyModel
>> new_obj = MyModel.objects.create(name="test",
                                password="test",
                                email_notification=1)
>> new_obj.email == ''
>> True
```

Ie,**Django `CharField` and `TextField` the default values are stored in the DB as an empty string (`''`)**. In other words, if you create an object without providing values for a `CharField`(or a `TextField`) under the hood Django invokes the `get_default` method and returns `''` (only in this case). This value will be stored in the database.

The following is the source code of [`get_default`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L796) method.

```
def get_default(self):
    """Return the default value for this field."""
    return self._get_default()

@cached_property
def _get_default(self):
    if self.has_default():
        if callable(self.default):
            return self.default
        return lambda: self.default

    if not self.empty_strings_allowed or self.null and not connection.features.interprets_empty_strings_as_nulls:
        return return_None
    return str  # return empty string
```

Let's answer your question:

> Why object got created,even if email field was mandatory?

The answer is `EmailField` is an instance of `CharField` Hence default value `''` will be used while  creating an object in database. That is why you are not getting `django.db.utils.IntegrityError`.

```
>> new_obj = Mymodel.objects.create(name='tes1t', password='test1', email_notification=1)
>>> new_obj.email
''
```

> Also if I go to the admin panel and open that object and click save then
> it raises an error indicating that email is required

Remember `blank` is different from `null`. `null` is purely database-related, whereas `blank` is validation-related. **So when you create an object directly in Python code, or execute raw SQL yourself, you are actually bypassing all of Django’s input validation.** But in  admin, Django is validating the input through the model form. Since in your case `blank` is set to False(blank not allowed), model form will raise `Email is required` Error.

Here is the relevant Django documentation for `blank` argument.

> Field.blank
>
> If True, the field is allowed to be blank. Default is  False.    Note
> that this is different than null. null is purely  database-related,
> whereas blank is validation-related. If a field has  blank=True, form
> validation will allow entry of an empty value. If a  field has
> blank=False, the field will be required.

Additional resources

- [Django tips: the difference between ‘blank’ and ‘null’](https://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/28/django-tips-difference-between-blank-and-null/)
- [differentiate null=True, blank=True in django](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8609425/6699447)

Comment: I explained the same thing in more easy way than a higher level overview :).

Answer (score 1):

*There is no issue with django you will have to create proper **Django Model Form validation** so that the empty string isn't ignored and it will raise an error for the blank field.*

Comment: Ya I have did that only, but why then the same object cannot be created via admin panel,if it can be done by the commands

Comment: Actually, admin panel is also built on top of Django Forms and they have used some form validation to check whether a required field is empty or not. You can perform the same validation by m.save(commit=False) which will not save the object actually and then you can perform a check whether the field is empty or not and raise exceptions accordingly.

Comment: so does that mean without form validation it will not stop creation of object as per the models constraints.validation will be necessary?

Comment: Yes, it is necessary. I also was stuck like you on one project back but later on I realized that we have to validate on our own and throw exceptions accordingly.