# Getting dropdown list id and save into view.py file using python django

Tags: python, django

This is my **models.py** file

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    join_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.today())
    end_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.today() + timedelta(days=7))
    package_status = models.BooleanField(default=True,blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    idboard= models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

 @receiver(post_save, sender=User) def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

instance.profile.save()
```

This is my **forms.py** file

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')

    phone_number = forms.CharField(help_text='Required. Format: 03001234567')
    idboard = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Board_TB.objects.filter(pk__in=b[1,2]),required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email','password1', 'password2','phone_number','idboard')
```

This is my **views.py** file

```
def signup(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':  
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():

            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()  

            user.profile.phone_number = form.cleaned_data.get('phone_number')
            user.profile.idboard = form.cleaned_data.get('idboard')
            user.save()

            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)

            return redirect('index')    
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()

    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html',{'form' : form,})
```

But I am facing this error:

> IntegrityError at /accounts/signup/
>       ('23000', "[23000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'idboard', table
>   'edxlinkdb.dbo.accounts_profile'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE
>   fails. (515) (SQLExecDirectW); [23000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native
>   Client 11.0][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)")

Comment: mention the values you have inserted

Comment: inserting value in idboard in view.py like punjab Board and Sindh Board

Comment: You got your error when post a form?

Comment: yes while posting in i am getting this error

Comment: check your `cleaned_data['idboard']` value. I guess it's null so the error occured

Comment: but i put blank=ture in model field

Comment: Tried to update field accounts.Profile.idboard with a model instance, <Board_TB: Sindh Board>. Use a value compatible with CharField.

Comment: @Tayyab Saleem '**but i put blank=ture in model field**'.  Both `Blank=True` and `null=True` are two different things. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51178466/6699447) for more detail.

Comment: @a_python_user i tried null=True now i am getting this error..."Tried to update field accounts.Profile.idboard with a model instance, <Board_TB: Punjab Board>. Use a value compatible with CharField."

Comment: You added both null=True and blank=True? I suggest not using `null=True` in `CharField`. use `blank=True` and `default=''`.

Comment: I have done ....Thankx alot guys specially @seuling