# How to ignore error instead of returning 400 Bad Request?- Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

I have a model named Cart. Cart has an Foreign Key to Coupon.

When I POST to create a new Cart, it runs some validations to find if Coupon exists. If not, it return Error 400 saying that the object does not exist.
I dont want an 400 Error, I need it to continue the processes returning Coupon as Null.

## serializers.py

```
class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(format='hex', read_only=True)
    delivery = DeliverySerializer(required=False, write_only=True)
    customer = CustomerSerializer(required=False, write_only=True)
    coupon = CouponSerializer(
    required=False,
    )
    totals = serializers.SerializerMethodField()


class CouponSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    code = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='code',
        required=False,
        source='coupon',
        queryset=Coupon.objects.only_valid(),
    )

    def to_representation(self, coupon):
        return {
            'code': coupon.code,
            'discount_amount': coupon.discount_amount,
            'discount_percentage': coupon.discount_percentage,
            'only_first_order': coupon.only_first_order,
        }
```

## views.py

```
class CartViewset(CreateModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Cart.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CartSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```

Comment: What do your models look like?

Comment: coupon = models.ForeignKey(
        'carts.Coupon',
        related_name='carts',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
    )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem doing as following:

Override the `to_internal_value` method from SlugRelatedField, treating the DoesNotExist exception to not raise an error.

```
class CouponSlugRelatedField(serializers.SlugRelatedField):

    def to_internal_value(self, code):
        try:
            return Coupon.objects.only_valid().get(code=code)
        except Coupon.DoesNotExist:
            return Coupon.objects.none()


class CouponSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    code = CouponSlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='code',
        required=False,
        source='coupon',
        allow_null=True,
        queryset=Coupon.objects.only_valid()
    )

    def to_representation(self, coupon):
        return {
            'code': coupon.code,
            'discount_amount': coupon.discount_amount,
            'discount_percentage': coupon.discount_percentage,
            'only_first_order': coupon.only_first_order,
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add blank=True to your model since it is a ForeignKey
coupon = `models.ForeignKey('carts.Coupon',related_name='carts',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True )`

Here is a good [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609192/differentiate-null-true-blank-true-in-django) about the difference of null and blank on models

Comment: I didn't solve the problem. I still get the exception Coupon.DoesNotExist when the user write a wrong Coupon code.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing null or a blank for the coupon id when posting. It sounds like something is being passed as an id when posting. There is no reason it should throw the exception if null or blank is being passed. If all else fails wrap the whole thing in a try except and catch the DNE error a just use pass

Comment: Yes, I'm sure because if I don't pass any code, it works as expected setting Coupon = Null.
The problem is when a wrong code is entered, then the Exception Object Does Not Exist.

Comment: What do you mean by wrong code? Like an incorrect id is entered? Maybe you could post a code example of what you mean

Comment: Yes, but i'm using SlugRelatedField, so it's not ID, its a Slug field named code.

Comment: Do you check what is being passed into that field when the post is being processed?

Comment: Also I could be wrong but I do not believe source is an attribute of slugrelatedfield. I just check the documentation and didn't see it mentioned anywhere and I never seen it used myself.

Comment: I found where the Exception is thrown. In the method `to_internal_value` for the SlugRelatedField. So I override this method, setting a `pass` to treat the Exception `ObjectDoesNotExist` and it works as expected. But now I get another error saying that Coupon object is not iterable. I'm investigating more about this and when I get a solution I answer here. Thanks

Comment: I caution you on doing it this way. It is essentially putting a band aide on something and not actually fixing it. This may cause much harder to diagnose problems in the future. My best guess is that is not your back end code but something on your front end.

Comment: Ok, but let me explain something. I don't know if you understand exactly what is my problem. If on POST I send empty Coupon code (slug), my Cart is created correctly with Coupon set to Null. If on POST I send a correct Coupon code (slug), my Cart is created with that Coupon associated correctly. But if I send a wrong Coupon code (slug), this object is not found on the queryset, so the API throws an Exception saying that Object Does Not Exist, and I receive a 400 error (bad request). I must ignore this Exception, I cannot receive a 400 error. My Cart must be created with Coupon set Null.

Comment: This makes more sense now, I wasn't fully understanding my apologize.  I would alter to the post action in your viewset to first check if the coupon exsists something like if else. If the coupon exists create it with the coupon and else create it setting it to null. I do not believe you will be able to achieve what you want just using unmodified view sets. You could also validate in your front end not even let it submit if it is not correct but that has problems that need to be considered as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Django REST Framework docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield), you need to set `allow_null=True` on the related field in your serializer:

```
class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(format='hex', read_only=True)
    delivery = DeliverySerializer(required=False, write_only=True)
    customer = CustomerSerializer(required=False, write_only=True)
    coupon = CouponSerializer(
    required=False,
    allow_null=True,
    )
    totals = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
```

Note that you'll need `null=True` in your `Cart` model as well.