# Django CharField equal to evaluation

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with Field like
`key = CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)`

when i check for the value after form submission like this.

`if self.key is None:`
the condition fails

But when i check for `if self.key == ''` it works.

My question is why it doesn't works when i evaluate it to `None` and works when i use `''`.

The `None` condition works only when i assign the values like this.
`key = CharField(max_length=100, null=True ,blank=True)`

I read some posts where it states that when evaluating the CharField as `blank=True` an empty string `''` is saved but they didn't shed any light why it does that. because as far i understand it should save a Null value.

Comment: Because if you type: type(self.key) you will get 'NoneType' in first case and 'str' in the second case, NoneType != str even if str is empty

Comment: I know that None !=str but my question is why it saves it as an empty string when blank=True is given to a Field?

Comment: Because blank=True only  prevents from cases when type is None and not str, even empty str

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between \`==\` and \`is\` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python)

Comment: Also, you can clear your doubts here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609192/differentiate-null-true-blank-true-in-django

Answer (score 1):

```
null = True
```

is about database which means you can have an object from your model that the value of field is null.

```
blank= True
```

is about django forms and means when you fill a `modelForm` of this model you can pass empty string and its not necessary to fill this field in your form.

So when you add `null = True` for the objects that have no value for key in the database key is `null` and in consequence `if self.key is None` works but when you remove this option for the objects in the database that have no value for key in database the key is `''` so your condition is not True.