# IntegrityError at /

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I've been trying creating a user profile form using built-in User of django.contrib.auth.models. Everything is working fine but after filling the fields into the form(which is displaying), I am encountering an INTEGRITY ERROR AT / saying NOT NULL CONSTRAINT failed.
[You can see this image using this link to know exactly what the error is showing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTCLN.png)

This is my models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator
# Create your models here.
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    phone_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators= 
    [MaxValueValidator(9999999999)],blank=True)


    def __str__(self): #This will print out this model
         return self.user.username
```

This is my forms.py file.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from Login_Signup_Form.models import UserProfileInfo

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

class Meta:   
    model=User
    fields=('first_name','last_name','username','email','password',)

    class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
             model=UserProfileInfo    #this is model
             fields=('phone_number',)
```

This is my views.py file.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from Login_Signup_Form.forms import UserForm,UserProfileForm
from Login_Signup_Form.models import UserProfileInfo
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
   return render(request,'base.html')

def register(request):
   registered=False

   if request.method == 'POST':
      user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)  
      user_phone_number=UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and user_phone_number.is_valid():
            user=user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            phone = user_phone_number.save()
            phone.user=user    
        else:
            #Printing the errors
            print(user_form.errors,user_phone_number.errors)
   else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        user_phone_number = UserProfileForm()


  return render(request, 'base.html',{'user_form':user_form, ' 
phone_number':user_phone_number})
```

Comment: Totally unrelated but a phone number is NOT an integer - it's a text value containing digits.

Answer (score 0):

The error probably comes from an empty phone number in your form. You allow an empty phone_number in your form with `blank=True` but you don't allow it on the database level, you need to add `null=True` as well:

```
phone_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators= 
[MaxValueValidator(9999999999)], blank=True, null=True)
```

See [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8609425/2528658).

With `blank=True` the field is not required and the form will validate but it will raise the integrity error because `null=True` is not here. That wouldn't happen with a `CharField` though, the blank value would be stored as empty string. This only happens because of the `PositiveIntegerField`.

Comment: With the field being required, the form wouldn't validate if the field wasn't filled, so it wouldn't even hit the database.

Comment: With `blank=True` the field is not required and the form will validate but it will raise the integrity error because `null=True` is not here (that wouldn't happen with a `CharField` though, the blank value would be stored as empty string). I think this only happens because of the `PositiveIntegerField`. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8609425/2528658). If I'm correct, please remove the downvote :)

Comment: you're right indeed, I should have read more carefully, my bad :-/ Could you please edit your post so I can undownvote it ?