# IntegrityError Null constraint violation

Tags: django, django-admin

I have three models in my django app...a `members` model, an `application` model and an `applications review` model.

My members model looks like this...

```
class Members(models.Model):
    TITLES = (
        ('chairman', 'Chairman'),
        ('secretary', 'Secretary')
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TITLES, default='secretary')
```

My Applications model...

```
class Application(models.Model):
   firstname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   middlename = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   lastname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   dob = DateField()
```

The applications review model...

```
class ApplicationsReview(models.Model):
    APPLICATION_STATUS = (
        ('pending', 'Pending Review'),
        ('approved', 'Approved'),
        ('rejected', 'Rejected')
    )
    applicant = models.OneToOneField(Application, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    chairman = models.ForeignKey(Members, related_name='chairs', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    secretary = models.ForeignKey(Members, related_name='secretaries', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    application_status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=APPLICATION_STATUS, default='pending')
    status_justification = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

When an application is created, I would like its review instantiated as well, hence, I have the following signal right below the applications review model...

```
# When an application is created, create with it an application review and associate it with the application instance

@receiver(post_save, sender=Application)
def create_application_review(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    created = kwargs['created']
    if created:
        ApplicationReview.objects.create(applicant=instance)
```

However, when I try to add an application in django admin I get the error

```
null value in column "chairman_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (3, pending, 2019-02-08 03:26:04.643452+00, null, null).
```

The error seems to be as a result of the signal trying to instantiate an `ApplicationsReview` instance without providing the values for the chairman and secretary. Even setting those to allow null fields doesn't get rid of the error. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Creating `ApplicationsReview` requires you to pass the following details - `chairman, secretary, status_justification` But while creating `ApplicationReview` in the signal you are just passing value of `applicant`, So Django is assuming the values of `chairman, secretary, status_justification` fields as Null that is why you are getting this error.

If you want to make these field Non-compulsory you can pass `null=True, Blank=True` while defining the field in the model.

Something like this:

```
chairman = models.ForeignKey(Members, null=True, blank=True, related_name='chairs', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

# End
```

You can refer this answer to get more understanding of when to use `null=True`, `blank=True` or both.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8609425/6280433

Comment: Great. But now that means the ApplicationsReview can be posted with the chairman and secretary fields being blank. Is there a way I can get around that?

Comment: The view which is creating `Application object` have the values of `chairman and secretary field`?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: Do you have any form for `ApplicationsReview`. If yes so there you can validate the form field if they are not empty.