# Annotate returning null on non-existent values and I want to convert this to null into empty string

Tags: django, string, django-rest-framework, null, annotate

I have two models , Customer and Purchase. I want to return the last store that the customer purchased from and order on this.

I can successfully show this list, showing last store the Customer purchased from, and being able to order on store name, using the following models, query/subquery.

```
# models
class Customer(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Purchase(models.Model):

    store = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=6)
    customerID = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                   related_name='purchases')
    order_date = models.DateField()

#viewset

#subquery
purchase_qs = Purchase.objects.filter(customerID=OuterRef("pk")).order_by("-order_date")

queryset = Customer.objects.all().annotate(last_purchase=Subquery(purchase_qs.values('store')[:1]))

ordering_fields = ['last_purchase']
```

My Current Output for Customers who have zero Purchases is.

"last_purchase":null

I want to have

"last_purchase":""

Answer (score 3):

`ForeignKey` fields automatically append `_id` to the name of the model field, so you'd need to use `customerId_id` to reference the `ForeignKey`.  Clearly this isn't what you want, so I'd recommend renaming the field to `customer` instead, also I think this is why your query is blank.

With that being said, you don't really need `Subquery` or `OuterRef` for this. Instead you can use the *reverse relation* of your `Customer` model, along with `Max`:

```
from django.db.models import Max

Customer.objects.select_related('Purchase').annotate(
    last_purchase = Max('purchases__order_date')
)
```

Lastly, the `null` key is False by default so no need to say `null=False`, and it doesn't make sense to have `blank=True` but `null=False`.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609192/differentiate-null-true-blank-true-in-django) for an excellent explanation about what the differences between `null` and `blank` are.

### Update

The [`Coalesce`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) function seems to be perfect for this scenario:

```
from django.db.models import Max, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Customer.objects.select_related('Purchase').annotate(
    last_purchase = Coalesce(Max('purchases__order_date', Value(''))
)
```

Comment: Yes, your example worked to, so a subqery is not necessary. I still have the issue of null getting returned on Customers who have not purchases. I had used the serializer 'to_representation' method to change null to empty string, but I want to have the value as empty string before it gets to the serializer. I guess I am looking for a conditional statement on the annotate, suche as Case-When, but I cannot get that to work.

Comment: The Coalesce worked and returned the empty string instead of null, thus avoiding doing this in the serialiser.