# In django model what are the pros and cons of setting null=True or blank=True?

Tags: mysql, django

In a django model, I usually take the lazy/easy way our to set all my CharFields to both null=True and blank=True.  I am going to remove one, but which one is more preferable to keep? 
I am using MySQL by the way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [differentiate null=True, blank=True in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609192/differentiate-null-true-blank-true-in-django)

Comment: you can check the docs here too: (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hi, it depends on what you want to achieve, you want to keep your data
>   clean in your DB tables, specially if you will need it for reporting
>   or dashboards. Anyway, for sake of your question and that the field is
>   a Charfield, null=True is unnecesary, this type is never stored or
>   saved as Null.