# Will Django UUIDFIeld unique=True, blank=True and null=True behave correctly?

Tags: django, django-models

I am adding a field to a database:

`identifier = models.UUIDField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)`

but I am curious if this will behave like a CharField or a number field when someone saves an instance in the admin without a value. Will it try to save the value as an empty string `""` or will it be smart and save it as `null`? I am using Postgres for the database. I've seen other [answers for CharField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609192/differentiate-null-true-blank-true-in-django), but nothing that speaks to UUIDField.

My end goal is to have a field that is guaranteed to be unique, and will default to `null`. would it be more appropriate to write it as:

`identifier = models.UUIDField(unique=True, null=True, default=None)` or will the admin form validation complain if no value is provided?

Comment: Why do you make it `null=True`?

Comment: As in why allow null? because this is an existing data base and the value for this field will be populated over time. almost all the instances will not have a value for this field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield) doesn't specify how `UUIDField` handles null values.

However, a look at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8dabdd2cc559a66b519e2a88b64575d304b96ebe/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L2299) shows that it's not a subset of `CharField`, and that it has explicit support for handling null values.

So it appears that the field will indeed store `None` values as `NULL`, and since such values are always unique on PostgreSQL your approach should work on that database.