# I am not able to add item to database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a product model, which i have the modelforms to make a form for and then implemented in my views and templates. After submitting the form, the product is not being added to the database and I don't know what the error seems to be.

I made sure to use the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` because of the image field in the form and also `request.FILES`.

***N.B:I am getting `Error Adding Product` which is the else statement if the form is not valid, but i don't know how the form is not valid.***

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/products', default='images/products/default-product.jpeg', blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_favourite = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='favourite', blank=True)
    country = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class AddProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['user']
```

views.py

```
@login_required
@supplier_required
def Addproduct(request):
    title = "Add New Product"
    form = AddProductForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Product Added Successfully")
            return redirect('product')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Error Adding Product")

    context = {"form":form, "title":title}

    return render(request, "core/addproduct.html", context)
```

addproduct.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
      {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
      {{ form.price|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
      {{ form.quantity|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
      {{ form.country|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
      {{ form.image|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
  </div>
  {{ form.description|as_crispy_field }}
  <button class="au-btn au-btn--block au-btn--green m-b-20" type="submit">Add Product</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What does `print(form.errors)` give? Also in your model you have a field `category` which is not nullable and not excluded in your form, yet you are not rendering it.

Comment: what is the different between null and blank please.

Comment: See [What is the difference between null=True and blank=True in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609192/what-is-the-difference-between-null-true-and-blank-true-in-django)

Comment: thanks sir. I got it

Comment: I was able to solve it with print(forms.errors). i noticed that the category was not added earlier