# How to automatically get Model Field type, its properties and size from other apps?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am developing API in DRF.

Django : 3.2.3

djangorestframework : 3.12.4

In my master_details App I've created a model with different fields. Some are mentioned bellow

```
class MasterModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(null=False, blank=True)
    data = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    ...
```

Similarly I have a report App which provide Get API endpoint to reporting tools. This report model shall contain certain fields that are same as/imported from MasterModel as shown bellow

```
class ReportModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(null=False, blank=True)
    data = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    ...
```

or

```
class ReportModel(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(MasterModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.ForeignKey(MasterModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data = models.ForeignKey(MasterModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

I am unable to use Foreign Key, in case data in MasterModel changes it will propagate to ReportModel. This should be avoided as historical reports must not be affected and the integrity of historical records must be maintained.

I have manually duplicated the fields in the ReportModel and I manually maintain their congruence. I wish to get around this.

I wish to know is their any automatic way whereby I can create Model Field type and apply its properties and size from other apps?

---

New Edit

As suggested I have added abstract model and it solved majority of my problem but a new issue propped up.

One of the field declared in the abstract model must be primary key in one particular model but not in the other models. How can this be achieved.

In the bellow example serial_number declared in abstract model must be primary key in details model but not in report detail models. How can this be achieved.

Abstract Model:

```
from django.db import models

class AbstractModel(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=8, primary_key=True, null=False, blank=False)
    class Meta :
        abstract = True
```

Detail Model:

```
class DetailModel(AbstractModel):
    class Meta :
        db_table = 'details'
    #serial_number must be primary key in Detail Model    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, blank=True, default='')
    ...
```

Details Report

```
class ReportDetailModel(AbstractModel):
    class Meta :
        db_table = 'report_details'
    #serial_number must not be primary key in Detail Model and will be duplicated in this table
    report_comment = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=True, default='')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you are trying to achieve is basically duplicate the fields in multiple models without copy-pasting. That can be achieved via inheritance, using an [abstract](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) model.

```
class BaseModel(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(null=False, blank=True)
    data = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class MasterModel(BaseModel):
    some_other_field = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ReportModel(BaseModel):
    pass
```

P.S. [don't use null=True on Char/Text fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8609425/6627564)

Comment: Thanks for the solutions. It worked but now I am facing a issue with abstract class. I have made a new edit to my question and summarized the problem bellow.
One of the field declared in the abstract model must be primary key in one particular model but not in the other models. How can this be achieved.

Comment: It may be simpler to just copy-paste and adjust in this case