# Django: Difference between blank=True and default=""

Tags: django, django-models

When declaring a model, there are many questions about `null` vs `blank` arguemnts (and this question is NOT about that)!

But what is the difference between if I mark a `django.db.models.CharField` with `default=""` vs `blank=True` ?

To me it seems like the same concept?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between null=True and blank=True in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609192/what-is-the-difference-between-null-true-and-blank-true-in-django)

Comment: @AnkitTiwari No, as stated in the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blank and Default arguments are not interchangeable.  The resulting interaction will be different, depending on what combination you use.  For example,

```
some_field = models.CharField(default='', max_length=20)
```

...will not allow you to *save the model instance* without entering data into some_field.  The default empty string in this case is just allowing you to add that field to the model upon migration, since you aren't also allowing null with null=True.

```
some_field = models.CharField(blank=True, default='', max_length=20)
```

...will save without data, since blank=True.

Another way of putting this is that your default='' is allowing the non-nullable field to exist, and blank=True is allowing your non-nullable field to save() without data entry.  If you try to migrate the following:

```
some_field = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

...you'll get the following error:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'some_string' to YourModelName without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

...since a non-nullable field without a default can't exist on the database, but a blank=True field can.  Note, I'm speaking here of PostgeSQL.  This may or may not apply to any/every other DB out there.

Answer (score -1):

**Field.null**
If **True**, Django will store empty values as **NULL** in the database. default is **False**.
Avoid using null in **CharField** or **TextField**

**Field.blank**
if **True**, the field is allowed to be blank. Default is **False**.

**NOTE:** This is different than **null. null** is purely database related, where **blank** is validation-related.

Comment: and `default=""` is the default for a field which must have `blank=True` in order for that default value to be acceptable.

Comment: There are many questions answering null vs blank, as stated in the original answer, the question is about blank vs default=''