# How i can create a muti value filed without manytomany field in django?

Tags: django, django-3.2

I have a model:

```
class People(models.Model):
   family = models.CharField(null=True)
   phone_numbers = ?
```

How i can implement `phone_numbers` for some phone numbers. I think `ManyToManyField` is not a good idea for doing this.

What is best practice for this?

admin.py

```
class PhonesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.Phones

class PeopleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        PhonesInline,
    ]
admin.site.register(models.People, PeopleAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create a `Phone` model and create a Many-to-one relationship between `Phone` and `People` using [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships). With this you can associate various phone numbers to a single person.

```py
class People(models.Model):
    family = models.CharField(null=True)


class Phone(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey(People, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now, for example, if you have a `People` instance in a variable called `people`, you can access its related phone numbers with [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list):

```
people.phone_set.values_list('number', flat=True)
```

As a note for your model, it's not recommended to use `null=True` to a `CharField/TextField`. The [official Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#null) states the following:

> Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and TextField. If a string-based field has null=True, that means it has two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty string. In most cases, it’s redundant to have two possible values for “no data;” the Django convention is to use the empty string, not NULL. One exception is when a CharField has both unique=True and blank=True set. In this situation, null=True is required to avoid unique constraint violations when saving multiple objects with blank values.

You can also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609192/what-is-the-difference-between-null-true-and-blank-true-in-django), which tackles my last point.

Also I don't know which logic you want to apply to your project, but I think a better way to organize your models and their relationships is to create a `Family` class to deal with families like:

```py
class Family(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class People(models.Model):
    family = models.ForeignKey(Family, blank=True, null=True)


class Phone(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey(People, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

With this extra model you will be able to create another Many-to-one relationship between `People` and `Family`. Depending on your needs, you should adapt the arguments when creating the fields, the ones I provided are just an example.

Comment: i attached admin.py