# django REST Framework - Integer field will not accept empty response?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The `models.py` IntegerField is set-up:

```
class DMCAModel(models.Model):
    tick = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    percent_calc = models.FloatField()
    ratio = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)   #The problem is here
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='dmca',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

serilaizers.py

```
class DMCASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DMCAModel
        fields = '__all__'
        # fields = ['id', 'tick', 'percent_calc', 'ratio']
# I have tried removing fields, if I remove 'ratio' then even if I send an input it is ignored.
```

api.py

```
class DmcaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # queryset = DMCAModel.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated
    ]

    serializer_class = DMCASerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.dmca.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        # print(self.request.user)
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

When I to make the following `POST` request from postman:

```
Authorization: Token xxxxxx
Body JSON:
{
"tick":"XYZ",
"percent_calc":"3",
"ratio":""
}
```

I get the error:

> {
> "ratio": [
> "A valid integer is required."
> ]
> }

I think I have set the properties of the `Models` field correctly if I understand them correctly: `null=True` database will set empty to `NULL`, `blank=True` form input will be accepted, `default=None` incase nothing is entered. I have tried to use the properties one by one and see what happens. But can't work out the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your serializer, you can use a CharField for the ratio field if you want to send an empty string and then convert to Int in the validation method.

```
class DMCASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     ratio = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)

     class Meta:
         model = DMCAModel
         fields = '__all__'

     def validate_ratio(self, value):
         if not value:
             return None
         try:
             return int(value)
         except ValueError:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Valid integer is required')
```

Also, you need to change *serializer_class* inside *DmcaViewSet* from:

```
serializer_class = DcaSerializer
```

to

```
serializer_class = DMCASerializer
```

When I send an empty string:

[image]

When I send an Integer:

[image]

Comment: Hi Milos, it still gives the same error. I have set the class Meta same as per my code as it wasn't included in yours.

Comment: Hi Sid, I updated the serializers.py. It should work.

Comment: Thanks Milos. It works. Will start reading up more about this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `default = True`. If `blank = True` then `default = False`, according to the docs.

But also, `null = True` means that the value will be **required** in forms. So removing `null = True` is also part of the solution.

Try this:

```py
class DMCAModel(models.Model):
    tick = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    percent_calc = models.FloatField()
    ratio = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='dmca', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Heres a useful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8609425/17597213) on the difference between `null` and `blank`, too. Its worth the read.

Comment: Still the same error. I removed `null=True` and `default=None`. Did `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

Comment: I read through the answer you mentioned. `blank=True, null=True` should be the solution. But it just doesn't seem to work on my end.

Comment: It seems to be an error in the `serializer`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try passing this request

```
Authorization: Token xxxxxx
Body JSON:
{
"tick":"XYZ",
"percent_calc":"3",
"ratio": null
}
```

If you ware passing empty string then at the end it is string so it will raise ValidationError, also you are using modelserializer so by default it will validate against the type of model field.
`blank=True` will not mean anything with integer.