# This field is required error in django default image

Tags: django

I set my imagefield as NONE but when i tried to enter data without image from django admin panel it is showing that This field is required.

this is my urls.py
`

```
class dish(models.Model):
    dish_id = models.AutoField
    dish_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dish_size = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    dish_price = models.IntegerField()
    dish_description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dish_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="", default=None)
    dish_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dish_name
```

`
How to set it as none if user not select any image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dish_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="", default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

Both `blank=True` and `null=True` are needed. Here’s why: [What is the difference between null=True and blank=True in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609192/what-is-the-difference-between-null-true-and-blank-true-in-django)

——-

Also, you don’t need `dish_id`. IDs are automatically generated and accessed with `model_instance.pk`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields