# TaggableManager with blank=True raise IntegrityError when creating object in admin panel

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-taggit

I have a model and an admin defined:

**models.py**

```
from adminsortable.models import Sortable

class Category(Sortable):
    site = models.ForeignKey('sites.Site', related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('Slug'), max_length=255, unique=True)
    icon = ImageField(_('Icon'), upload_to='myapp/icons')
    icon2 = ImageField(_('Icon 2'), upload_to='myapp/icons')
    recommended_tags = TaggableManager(related_name='category', blank=True)
```

**admin.py**

```
from adminsortable.admin import SortableAdmin

class CategoryAdmin(SortableAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'site']
    list_filter = ['site',]

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

Looks like everything is fine but I get an IntegrityError when I try to create an object from admin panel. What's interesting, the object update is working fine. The problem is just when I try to create a new Category object.

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "recommended_tags" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (64, ggggggggg, ggggggggg, myapp/icons/16.jpg, 31, myapp/icons/46.jpg, 1, null).
```

It is probably caused at admin `save_model()` method but I am not sure.

django 1.11

django-taggit 0.22.2

postgres database

Comment: You probably need `null=True`. Read more about difference between Django null and blank [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384098/in-django-models-py-whats-the-difference-between-default-null-and-blank)

Comment: @SohaibFarooqi due to django-taggit docs, there is just blank parameter possible to set. https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Comment: Could be an issue with the version. Django-Taggit [change logs](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html) mentions several occurrences of `IntegrityError` happening and these are backwards incompatible. I would suggest you to give it a try with recommended version of library and Django.